# Hide fixed content after scroll to specific position?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, css-float, jquery-events

I used this (https://github.com/cheald/floatingFixed) Javascript to create social sharing bar on my site. Its working great but I don't want to show it when it is scrolled into footer of page. How to do this? Here's one of my site's page http://thedripple.com/1384/lg-optimus-g-launch-price/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite straight-forward since you already include jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() { //when scrolled
    var flt = $(".floater");
    var offset = flt.offset().top + flt.height(); //get the current offset of the floater
    var footertop = $("#footer").offset().top; //and the footer's top offset
    if(offset > footertop) { //if you scrolled past the footer
        flt.hide(); //hide the sharing tab
    }
    else {
        flt.show(); //show it
    }
});
```

Comment: He'll probably want to add the height of `floater` to the y-offset of the window.

Comment: In fact, it's probably better to find the offset of `floater` instead of the y-offset of the window, as it will include any other positioning (margin, etc).